# voice recognition program using C#

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, voice-recognition

Im trying to build a voice recognition program based on this link :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJdVfwiTIXE

The problem is..When I run the windows form after compiling, it is not recognizing and responding to my voice commands...I am using .NET framework 4 client profile for this project. I made reference only to "system.speech" and Im using the build in microphone of my laptop for voice input..

Here is my text file(i wrote it line by line from the first line):

```
hi
hello henry
close
close henry
```

Here is my code so far :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.IO;

namespace Henry
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        SpeechSynthesizer Henry = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        Random rnd = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Henry\com.txt")))));
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
            _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }

        void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            int ranNum = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            string speech = e.Result.Text;
            switch (speech)
            {
                //GREETINGS
                case "hi":
                case "hello henry":
                    if (ranNum < 6) { Henry.Speak("Hello sir"); }
                    else if (ranNum > 5) { Henry.Speak("Hi"); }
                    break;

                case "close":
                case "close henry":
                    Henry.Speak("Until next time");
                    Close();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhat obvious question - what *do* you get as recognized text (just trace value of `speech` or look at it in debugger) - likely it will solve the problem...

Comment: when I insert the break point, the value of speech cannot be traced..However I get these messages..Does this mean something..Im quite new to speech recognition..SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection.. A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Speech.dll A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Speech.dll A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Speech.dll

Comment: Same question, same author here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198683/sapi-does-not-implement-phonetic-alphabet-selection-exception