# 'SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection' exception

Tags: c#, .net, dll, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

Whenever I attempt to code any speech recognition program in my laptop,I always get the same messages as mentioned below..I can always compile my code and get the windows form application working..But the problem is, the program will not detect my voice..And the program wont work..

I am very sure my codes works fine as I usually take the codes from youtube videos like : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KR0-UYUGYgA and many more..
I am using .NET framework 4 client profile for my projects.. I make reference only to "system.speech"...What might be my problem ?

Debug messages that I get :

```
speaker.vshost.exe Information: 0 : SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Speech.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Speech.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Speech.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Speech.dll
```

Sample code that I tried :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace speaker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SpeechSynthesizer sSynth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        PromptBuilder pBuilder = new PromptBuilder();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sRecognize = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pBuilder.ClearContent();
            pBuilder.AppendText(textBox1.Text);
            sSynth.Speak(pBuilder);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = true;
            Choices sList = new Choices();
            sList.Add(new string[]{"hello","test","it works","how","are","you","today"});
            Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(sList));

            try
            {
                sRecognize.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
                sRecognize.LoadGrammar(gr);
                sRecognize.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sRecognize_SpeechRecognized);
                sRecognize.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                sRecognize.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (e.Result.Confidence >= 0.3)
            MessageBox.Show("speech is:" + e.Result.Text.ToString());
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You are hiding bugs in your code with the try/catch-em-all statements.  Calling SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice() is not valid when speech recognition is in progress.  Subscribing the SpeechRecognized event multiple times is a drastic bug as well.  You've got some more work to do, never hide an inconvenient truth.

Comment: @HansPassant..ok ..instead of Calling SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice() , what should I do in my code ? I would like to use the build in microphone in my laptop as the input device..

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
 gram.Culture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")
```

For more details see

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?751297-RESOLVED-(VS2102)-Speech-Recognition-Suddenly-Stopped

Comment: ...Adding gr.Culture = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB") into my code gives this error : 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' is a 'type',which is not valid in the given context..how do i resolve this ?

Comment: in C# it's `grammarBuilder.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"); gr = new Grammar(grammarBuilder);`

Comment: Still hv error..for the first line,An object reference is required for the non-static field,method or property 'System.Speech.Recognition.GrammarBuilder.get'...for the 2nd line, 'System.Speech.Recognition.GrammarBuilder' is a 'type' but is used like a'variable'..It will be valuable for me if u relate ur answer to my sample code as im new to C# & speech recognition..thank you